# A spiral sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, hexagonal-grid

## Background

OEIS sequence [A272573](https://oeis.org/A272573) describes a spiral on a hexagonal grid as follows:

> Start a spiral of numbers on a hexagonal tiling, with the initial hexagon as a(1) = 1. a(n) is the smallest positive integer not equal to or previously adjacent to its neighbors.

The sequence begins

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9, 8, 10, 2, 11, ...
```

Here's an illustration of the spiral pattern:
[image]

- `a(11) != 1` because then `3` and `1` would be adjacent in two places.
- `a(11) != 2` because then `3` and `2` would be adjacent in two places.
- `a(11) != 3` because then `3` would be adjacent to itself.
- `a(11) != 4` because then `3` and `4` would be adjacent in two places.
- Therefore `a(11) = 5`.

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a program that computes [A272573](https://oeis.org/A272573). This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: I can't see the image as it's blocked here, so maybe I'm missing something, but your example shows a(11)=4, but in your sequence list a(11) is 5.

Comment: Just a mistake—thanks for catching it.

Comment: This OEIS sequence was submitted by yourself, apparently. Nice. :)

Comment: what is the limit for n ? is there a time limit ?

Comment: @Setop, you just have to write a program which computes the sequence correctly, and could determine an arbitrary value in the sequence given enough time/memory/etc.

Comment: Awaiting Hexagony answer...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>267 .. 206</s>  199 bytes

Returns an array containing the \$N\$ first terms of the sequence.

```javascript
n=>(F=v=>++i<n?F([...v,(A=N[i]=[1,!j++||d+1,j%L?d:(j%=L*6)?++d:L++&&d++].map(k=>N[k=i-k].push(i)&&k),g=k=>v[E='every']((V,x)=>V-k|N[x][E](y=>A[E](z=>v[y]-v[z])))?k:g(-~k))()]):v)([L=1],N=[[i=j=d=0]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxboMwEIDhV2mHwF1tLBiaAeVAGZIJMWaxbkAxobYTQKG1QoT66rSZ/uH7XROa6Xy343fSD6ZdL7T2VMCRAhVC2F1fHkErpYKEPdXaMulMvjshlsWITLpNVZoc3Iaqjy2WQpi8EiKKjBCsbs0Inopae7KJZzX@TF9gMYo8yo7@JegDxW1o73PMACf5QCpOiV9q/WB9YJip2L/6fK0zJ0E/GRFLn3eQ/HpEQMY8IOiKMpY1aW3JkaGUGdfz0E/DtVXXoYMLfKYpKjfYHmL5FiOufw)

### How?

#### Definitions

By convention, we will call ***corner-cell*** a cell that has only one edge in common with the previous layer of the spiral and ***side-cell*** a cell that has two edges in common with the previous layer. As [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48051895#48051895) by Ourous, we can also think of them as order-1 cells and order-2 cells, respectively.

Corner-cells are shown in yellow below. All other cells are side-cells (except the center cell which is a special case).

[image: cell types]

#### About cell neighbors

We don't really need to keep track of the coordinates of the cells on the grid. The only thing that we need to know is the list of neighbor cells for each cell in the spiral at any given time.

In the following diagrams, neighbors in the previous layer are shown in light shade and additional neighbors in the current layer in darker shade.

A cell has **2 neighbors** among the previous cells if:

- it's the first side-cell of a new layer (like **8**)
- or it's a corner-cell, but not the last one of the layer (like **9**)

[image: 2 neighbors]

A cell has **3 neighbors** among the previous cells if:

- it's a side-cell, but not the first one of the layer (like **10**)
- or it's the last corner-cell of the current layer (like **19**)

[image: 3 neighbors]

#### Implementation of cell neighbors

The index of the current cell (starting at \$1\$) is stored in \$i\$. The list of neighbors of a cell \$n\$ is stored in \$A[n]\$.

For obscure golfing reasons, we first compute the opposite offsets of the neighbors. For instance, \$1\$ means \$-1\$, which means *the previous cell*.

```javascript
[                    //
  1,                 // the previous cell is always a neighbor of the current cell
  !j++ || d + 1,     // if this is not the first cell of the layer, the cell at -(d + 1)
                     // is a neighbor (otherwise, we insert 1 twice; doing it that way
                     // saves bytes and having duplicate neighbors is not a problem)
  j % L ?            // if this is a side-cell:
    d                //   the cell at -d is a neighbor
  :                  // else (corner-cell):
    (j %= L * 6) ?   //   if this is not the last cell:
      ++d            //     insert the dummy duplicate neighbor at -(d + 1); increment d
    :                //   else (last cell):
      L++ && d++     //     the cell at -d is a neighbor; increment L; increment d
]                    //
```

In the above code:

- \$L\$ is the index of the current layer, starting at \$1\$ (and not counting the center cell).
- \$j\$ is the index of the current cell within the current layer, going from \$1\$ to \$6\times L\$.
- \$d\$ is the distance of the current cell to those of the previous layer. It is incremented each time we go through a corner cell.

We then process a `map()` loop which converts the offsets \$k\$ into indices (\$i-k\$) and push the current cell as a new neighbor for all neighbor cells, to enforce neighborhood symmetry.

```javascript
.map(k =>
  N[k = i - k].push(i) && k
)
```

#### Finding the next term of the sequence

Now that we have an up-to-date list of neighbors for all cells, we can finally compute the next term \$k\$ of the sequence, using another recursive helper function.

The value of a cell \$n\$ is stored in \$v[n]\$.

```javascript
( g =                 // g = recursive function taking
  k =>                // the candidate value k
    v.every((V, x) => // for each previous cell of value V at position x, make sure that:
      V - k           //   V is not equal to k
      |               //   OR
      N[x].every(y => //   for each neighbor y of x:
        A.every(z =>  //     for each neighbor z of the current cell:
          v[y] - v[z] //       the value of y is not equal to the value of z
        )             //     end
      )               //   end
    )                 // end
    ?                 // if the above conditions are fulfilled:
      k               //   stop recursion and return k
    :                 // else:
      g(-~k)          //   try again with k + 1
)()                   // initial call to g with k undefined (this will cause V - k to be
                      // evaluated as NaN and force the 1st iteration to fail)
```

Comment: Great explanation. One possible improvement: making the explanations in the code blocks fully visible without the need for horizontal scrolling (doesn't matter for the golfed code). Viewing in Firefox, there are 5 hidden columns in the first explanation code block, and 6 hidden columns in the second.

Comment: @trichoplax Thank you for your comment and suggestion. Could you specify which version of Firefox you're using and on which platform? I always try to format explanation blocks so that no horizontal scrolling is needed. I'm on Firefox 65 / Win10 right now and I don't have any hidden column.

Comment: Will check the version of Firefox when I get home, but it might be because I'm on Fedora. Will check on another OS and let you know

Comment: It does seem to vary by OS. Will raise this on MSE when I've had a chance to gather some evidence (if it hasn't been already)

Comment: I've [raised this on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324567/code-blocks-cut-off-at-different-widths-on-different-operating-systems). Feel free to edit if anyone sees other OS/browser combinations that show horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: @trichoplax Just for reference: on my PC, the selected font for code blocks is _Consolas_ and I still have a margin of 6 blank columns on the longest line.

Answer (score 7):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>284</s> <s>279</s> <s>272</s> 262 bytes

```
import StdEnv
l=[0,-1,-1,0,1,1]
c(u,v)(p,q)=(u-p)^2+(v-q)^2<2||(u-p)*(q-v)==1
$[h:t]m=hd[[e: $t[(h,e):m]]\\e<-[1..]|and[e<>j\\(u,v)<-m|c h u,(p,q)<-m|q==v,(i,j)<-m|c p i]]
```

```
$(scan(\(a,b)(u,v)=(a-u,b-v))(0,0)[(i,j)\\n<-[1..],i<-[1,1:l]&j<-l,_<-[max(~j<<i)1..n]])[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVDBTsMwDL33K3KYkAPO1O5YJZzggMQBacckoJBmNFWStVtbgVTx6ZSuDMmS/Wy/9yzb4Eya47EagiPR@DT72B5PPdn31WMasyBkjqy4RI4FFjqzMOBIocWOChhYS193dzCybsl8N01r6xY6NlIhimwj67LXUdSVlK4km15CjY6WUWulHGey2G71ZFIlHb9vlFrFOYuTJTUZcLW5wE6IEcFjcx22xGs9n103uGQdEWQDZ2sSKDD4TlcVAYYN@L4cQiHHnMqVrlS6uqK/FFiUQd80nAV8W3A0n/DdcO7pspK0plJn@94sDxHk323@sYdgPs4ze3qeH76Sid7@gZdg@sPxFH8B)

Generates the sequence forever.

**Hexagon Mapping**

Most of the code goes into mapping hexagons uniquely to `(x,y)` coordinates so that there's a single, simple function to determine adjacency which holds for all point mappings.

The mapped points look like this:

```
              ---
        --- < 2,-2> ---       x-axis ___.X'
  --- < 1,-2> === < 2,-1> ---  /__.X'
< 0,-2> === < 1,-1> === < 2, 0>'
  === < 0,-1> === < 1, 0> ===
<-1,-1> === < 0, 0> === < 1, 1>
  === <-1, 0> === < 0, 1> ===
<-2, 0> === <-1, 1> === < 0, 2>.__
  --- <-2, 1> === <-1, 2> ---  \  'Y.___
        --- <-2, 2> ---       y-axis    'Y.
              ---
```

From there, determining adjacency is trivial, and occurs when one of:

- `x1 == x2` and `abs(y1-y2) == 1`
- `y1 == y2` and `abs(x1-x2) == 1`
- `y1 == y2 - 1` and `x2 == x1 - 1`
- `y1 == y2 + 1` and `x2 == x1 + 1`
- `x1 == x2` and `y1 == y2`

**Point Generation**

Notice that when traversing the hexagon in a spiral the differences recur for each layer `n`:

1. `n` steps of `(1,0)`
2. `n-1` steps of `(1,-1)`
3. `n` steps of `(0,-1)`
4. `n` steps of `(-1,0)`
5. `n` steps of `(-1,1)`
6. `n` steps of `(0,1)`

This generates the points in the right order by taking sums of prefixes of this sequence:

```
scan(\(a,b)(u,v)=(a-u,b-v))(0,0)[(i,j)\\n<-[1..],i<-[1,1:l]&j<-l,_<-[max(~j<<i)1..n]]
```

**Bringing it Together**

The code that actually finds the sequence from the question is just:

```
$[h:t]m=hd[[e: $t[(h,e):m]]\\e<-[1..]|and[e<>j\\(u,v)<-m|c h u,(p,q)<-m|q==v,(i,j)<-m|c p i]]
```

Which in turn is mostly filtering by `and[r<>j\\(u,v)<-m|c h u,(p,q)<-m|q==v,(i,j)<-m|c p i]`

This filter takes points from `m` (the list of already-mapped points) by:

- Ignoring natural numbers that are equal to any `j`
- For every `(i,j)` where `i` is adjacent to `p`
- For every `(p,q)` where the value `q` is equal to `v`
- For every `(u,v)` where `u` is adjacent to the current point